# Can I ask about the impact of using TCP over UDP protocol for an instant messenger call feature?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, recommendation-questions

Let's suppose that I wanted to make an instant messenger software with a call and/or a video feature.

If I were to ask such a question:

- There wouldn't be much code to show.
- Although it's about transfer protocol, it doesn't sound like it belongs to the Network Engineering SE (since it's a software design question).
- It sounds slightly too broad, or the answer could be "just try it out and see for yourself" (or it's not actually a question about programming, despite being about its design).

Though I stumbled on some questions about TCP/UDP protocols on SO (with their appropriate tags), they weren't the same kind of question.

Considering these different points, would it be relevant to ask such a question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It's a protocol design problem long before it becomes a software design question, and it's clearly still in the first stage and nowhere near the second.

Comment: @BenVoigt What I believed to be a software design question was how it was going to impact user experience (will the video freeze out when data is missing, which in turn will create a lag between what they see and what's actually happening?). But as both you and Makoto pointed out, it's still too abstract to actually provide an answer.

Comment: You will need application protocols on top of TCP/UDP, and the choice depends on your requirement spec, (eg. max allowable latency, max number/size of buffers etc).  We cannot do your system design - it's not appropriate for a Q&A format, even if anyone wished to do the analysis and design for free, (very unlikely).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Honestly, it sounds too broad.  You're still trying to whiteboard this out and you don't have anything concrete down yet (to the point that you're trying to decide which kind of packet you want to use for this application).

We *really* wouldn't be of any value to you here.

Comment: I'm not sure we wouldn't bring any value to the table in such discussion, but as per the site rules we _can't_ bring any value but use our close votes as you mentioned.

Comment: @kayess:  Even *if* we did know what there was to know about telephony and VoIP, the premise of the question is too broad to even broach.  The detail being asked about is too minute and granular for us to really be of much service to them.  The site rules say we can't because it *really* is too broad.